# Barebone ATSAMD21G - start with IO on breadboard

Tags: microcontroller, atmel

In my quest to learn about microcontrollers, I did reach a result that for me is pretty exciting: I am able to upload code to a barebone ATSAMD21G, connected to a breadboard, using my ICE programmer. So far I was able to blink a led; which is basically the "hello world" of hardware, from what I understand.
I did write the code in Atmel studio.

Now the next step is to actually do something more, and so I am looking at IO. the SAMD21G uses SERCOM ports; which from what I can read on the datasheet, are programmable via muxing, so you have N pins, and X sercom ports, of which, each one has 5 pads to set IO as SPI, I2C or UART.

Now; the issue that I am facing, is that I can't find a tutorial that walk me through the configuration needed to actually use the microcontroller ports, for IO.

The examples on Atmel site, are related to their breakout board; same goes for other internet sources, that basically refer to their implementation of the SAMD21, without showing how did they actually end up there, with a config file set for the muxing, and with the bootloader on it.

My objective is to learn this, but I am having hard time to do so, since I have just a bare SAMD21, connected to the caps for power, a voltage regulator and the pins coming from the ICE (and a led now, yay!!); so I have no clue about what to do next, since it is not like loading arduino ide and start to code.

Any help would be really appreciated; if it is in detail and aimed at beginners, even better. I am fundamentally going in circle at this point, and learning on the reference board didn't give me any indication about how to do my configuration, sadly.

Comment: This is a good example of the many situations where you will be faced with a sea of possibilities, little guidance, and some rocks and shoals that will be painfully surprising when discovered.  One thing you can do is to pay more attention to examples, perhaps replicating the relevant parts of the Atmel board.  Note also that the SAMD21G is used in both the Arduino Zero and the Adafruit Feather.  If you give up on Atmel studio you can get Atmel's libraries separately, but you'll find location the needed pieces within quite a learning experience.

Comment: Indeed it is exciting, but also depressing, due to the total lack of guidance.
Now, considering that they sell the chips and do not give them away for free, I would think that would be in their interest to build up some examples :) I am from the software world, and when a software has a bad API or poor documentation, usually is dropped in favor of a similar product with such "commodities". Here it is really a matter to use stick and stones :)

Comment: To be specific on what I am trying to learn: first what is required as far as files goes, to have the bare minimum. My LED solution has a ton of files, and I have no clue about what is needed, what is extra, and in particular, where do you make the changes to assign IO and do the muxing.
Sadly the example for the reference board is nothing like the example that I have on Atmel studio, so I can't really follow along. Took me quite some time even to get a single example that run a simple blink program, but it is an exciting journey. I just wish it was less nebulous